# YARP - How to modify subapplication path?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, proxy, ms-yarp

## My Scenario

I have the following IIS site:

[www.site.com](http://www.site.com)

Calling [www.site.com/Login](http://www.site.com/Login) redirects correctly to the page in my subapplication, the browser bar shows [www.site.com/Login](http://www.site.com/Login).

But, calling [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), redirects to [www.site.com/subapplication/Login](http://www.site.com/subapplication/Login), it also works, but I want [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) to show [www.site.com/Login](http://www.site.com/Login) in the browser bar.

## IIS Structure

[www.site.com](http://www.site.com) is a .NET Core site with YARP

[www.site.com/subapplication/Login](http://www.site.com/subapplication/Login) is a .NET Framework site

## appsettings.json

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "fallbackRoute": {
        "ClusterId": "fallbackCluster",
        "Order": "1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          { "PathRemovePrefix": "/web" }
          { "RequestHeaderOriginalHost": "true" }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "fallbackCluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "fallbackApp": {
            "Address": "https://dansaleswebdev.danone.com.br/dev/web/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

## What I want

[www.site.com](http://www.site.com) redirect to [www.site.com/Login](http://www.site.com/Login) instead of [www.site.com/subapplication/Login](http://www.site.com/subapplication/Login)

I already tried to add the [PathRemovePrefix transformation](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/transforms.html#pathremoveprefix) to remove /subapplication but it not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Tratcher](https://github.com/Tratcher) on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/discussions/1844).

See [#1548](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/issues/1548).

You either need to change the framework app to generate the public urls, or you need to re-write the location header on the response.